# How to get and set variables from console application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, process, console-application

I have a .net app that calls a .net core app using the following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
var startInfo = p.StartInfo;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = "myDotNetCoreApp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += P_OutputDataReceived;
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
```

As you can see I'm setting strings (`argument`) on the Main method of console app and I'm getting it like this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var inputCommands = args[0].Split(",");
    ...
  }
```

Also, I catch `Console.WriteLine()` "event" and doing some actions. I have a method in the console app and it returns bool type. Now from the .net app, I need to know what result was returned from the method. I could do it like `Console.WriteLine("Method returned true")` but it doesn't like me. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Please, share .NET core app as well

Comment: The return value from an exe is the exit code.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: ^--- this along with `System.Environment.Exit(YourExitCode);` to close the called program with a specific code or `static int Main(...) { ... return YourExitCode; }`

Comment: @Cid OK, how can I get my YourExitCode from process?

Comment: @DIlshodK check the link provided by jdwend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Cid's comment:

In your myDotNetCoreApp app close your app using:

```
System.Environment.Exit(0)
```

0 means your app closed successfully

Then use this to get info from myDotNetCoreApp

```
Process p = new Process();
var startInfo = p.StartInfo;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = "myDotNetCoreApp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += P_OutputDataReceived;
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
if(p.ExitCode==0){
//Do some...
}
```